# Preventing the on-Click listener from calling itself on hidden views in Android app

Tags: android, view, onclicklistener

I've design the user interface of my app as a collection of views, not activities or fragments. I manage the showing and hiding of views on this collection of views which are right on top of each other.

I believe I chose the wrong design principle to use for my app. The problem I am having is that when I hide a view in order to show another one; the button that resides on the hidden view fires its on-Click listener.

After reading some of the Android Reference documentation, I see that the view tree will navigate down the hierarchy of views in order to consume the touch event. It is then that the on-Click listener of this button is called.

What I need is something to prevent the button from the hidden view to stop calling itself when the user touches the shown view. I know that calling setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE) stops the on-Click listener from being called.

I was thinking of the ViewTreeObserver class that will allow me to create a listener of view hierarchy that somehow allows me to get a handle of all the hidden views in order to call setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE) on the hidden views.

Any ideas or advice

Comment: You can remove listener `pass (null)` when you hide view and set listener for which is visible.

Comment: That is a good idea. But, how do I do it for all the hidden views? I don't want to be writing 30+ lines of setOnClickListener(null) on each of the hidden views. But, the other problem will be that I will need to enable the original onClicklistener after setting it to null. It will be a lot of work to do this for each of the views. @JeelVankhede

Answer (score 1):

When you do `setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE)` for a view, it will still present in the layout. So instead of `setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE)`, try `setVisibility(View.GONE)`.

This will remove the view completely from the layout including the onClickListner attached to it.

When you want that view back, you can use `setVisibility(View.VISIBLE)` to get it back.